# What is the State of a MOSFET with a Constant Source Current and Floating Gate?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, bjt

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7RxpS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Suppose we have a NMOS transistor, with and ideal current source (I_S) in its source. The drain is connected to V_DD, and the gate is just floating. It certainly cannot be cut-off since we have forced a current in its source, but is it triode or saturated? What if we change the MOS transistor to a BJT?

Comment: In general, for any significant current, the ending state is what senior engineers call "burnt up".  The part would go into breakdown (avalanche in the case of the BJT; I'm not sure what FETs do in that circumstance).  If you did this in the real world with a FET the results would be extremely unpredictable, because the open-circuit source could float to nearly any voltage.

Comment: Are we talking about an nMOS or pMOS here? Where is the current source "pointing" to? Can you include a schematic with our built-in schematic editor so we can see what you're talking about?

Comment: @KingDuken Yes, NMOS and the current source pointing down (from source to ground)

Comment: @TimWescott I thought maybe if it's in saturation mode, the I_S would dictate a certain V_GS and thus a certain gate voltage, but the problem is I cannot decide if it's saturated or triode.

Comment: *The gate looks like a capacitor*.  This means that \$V_{GS}\$ is more or less arbitrary, and in the real world will be *strongly* influenced by external forces.  In a simulated environment (which you can try for yourself, with the simulation environment that @KingDuken mentioned), the rising drain voltage *might* pull the gate voltage up enough for it to conduct enough for the transistor to naturally pass enough current to avoid voltage breakdown -- or it might not.  In a *real* environment, with who-knows-what parasitic resistances, all bets are off.

Comment: "since we have forced a current in its source" - No, you haven't.  Connecting a current source to an open circuit does not "force" anything.  If the potential difference between the gate and source is not enough to enhance the channel, there will be no current.

Comment: Deep-ending on how idealised the FET is the source will be at 10 or 1000 or 1,000,000 or .... volts . | You cannot play "apply random undefined unspecified out of bounds" conditions and expect other than random undefined unspecified out of bounds results.

Comment: Your question asks about a MOSFET, but your schematic shows a JFET. Can you edit to clarify?

Comment: `but is it triode or saturated?` That really depends on what \$I_S\$ and \$V_{DD}\$. Also, the fact that you have no gate connection anywhere can create some ambiguity. If you ground your gate, however, this could really eliminate ambiguity. If you swapped out the FET for a BJT, then it would _really_ depend \$I_S\$ if you keep the nomenclature the same. I think Tim's first comment is really the true answer you have. Due to the unpredictable nature of the gate, it could really make the transistor behave rather peculiarly.

Comment: @KingDuken I guess if it was a BJT it would definitely be in saturation (where V_CE < V_CE_Sat), because in BJT's active mode, base must have a current ((1/beta)*I_S) (which it cannot here).

Comment: what state depends on Vgs, which is indeterminate.

Comment: Your question is nonsensical. You can't force a value of \$I_{DS}\$ and expect \$V_{GS}\$ to magically change. The voltage across your current source will increase until the MOSFET is destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schematic shows a P-channel MOSFET, but operation is the same for NMOS.

When the Gate is 'floating' it will have a voltage determined by whatever charge was stored on it before being put in the circuit. So it might be cut off or it not might not be, depending on its previous history.

An 'ideal' MOSFET has no leakage and no breakdown voltage. If your circuit had only 'ideal' components and V<sub>GS</sub> was zero, then the ideal FET would be perfectly cut off and the ideal current would produce *infinite* voltage across it (which is impossible of course, but when an unstoppable current meets infinite resistance...).

But real FETs do have these 'flaws', so in practice it would at least pass the constant current corresponding to the leakage current at the voltage required to produce it. If the constant current was higher than the leakage current at normal operating voltage then V<sub>DS</sub> would increase until it reached the avalanche breakdown region, where the FET would act like a Zener.

If the floating Gate had sufficient charge to turn the FET on enough to keep V<sub>DS</sub> below the breakdown voltage then it would either be in the linear or saturated region, depending on V<sub>DS</sub> and I<sub>D</sub>.

(Graph from [Toshiba app note 20810726: Selecting MOSFETs and Consideration for Circuit Design](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=13416))
[image]

Bipolar transistors behave similarly, except the Base needs continuous current to keep the transistor turned on. So if the Base was open circuit the transistor would stay cut off until reaching its breakdown voltage. The curve trace below was taken from a PNP transistor rated for a maximum V<sub>CEO</sub> of -25V. It shows a smooth breakdown transition at ~-30V, drawing ~6mA at -35V. (the sharp drop at the bottom left of the curve is caused by reverse Base-Emitter breakdown at ~+6V).

Many bipolar transistors have a negative resistance characteristic in the breakdown region, where as current increases the voltage drops to a lower value called V<sub>CEO(sus)</sub> (sustaining voltage). This shows up on the curve tracer as an instability at the breakdown transition.

[image]